# Парсинг PDF Python. Сканнированные страницы

Tags: python, парсер, pdf

подскажите, есть ли разница между парсингом пдф конвертированного из ворда и парсингом пдф сделанного из сканнов страниц(даже хороших сканов). Я читал что разницы нет, так как все переводиться в рисунки, но я в этом не уверенн. И если есть разница, то можно ли получить внятный текст с помощью OpenCV(например) и ему подобных или вся надежда на ABBYY?

Comment: Не совсем так. Есть понятие PDF со слоем текста.

Comment: То есть, парсить PDF сделанный из ворда и парсить PDF из сканированных листов разные вещи?

Comment: Все зависит от того как ПДФ сохранен. Есть ли слои и пр. Можно и из Ворда сохранить как изображение.

Comment: Если в PDF есть текст, то работают достаточно простые (а, главное, быстрые) конвертеры. Поищите по словам pdf to text(pdf2text). На неизвестном PDF просто проверьте, можно ли скопировать текст в буфер. Если же там картинка - надо использовать бесплатный tesseract, или платный abbyy. Да, для извлечения текста есть и питоновский модуль, но есть и засада, мне попадались PDF, в которых тест был кривоватый, хотя визуально они смотрелись нормально.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если в PDF есть текст, то работают достаточно простые (а, главное,
>   быстрые) конвертеры. Поищите по словам pdf to text(pdf2text). На
>   неизвестном PDF просто проверьте, можно ли скопировать текст в буфер.
>   Если же там картинка - надо использовать бесплатный tesseract, или
>   платный abbyy. Да, для извлечения текста есть и питоновский модуль, но
>   есть и засада, мне попадались PDF, в которых тест был кривоватый, хотя
>   визуально они смотрелись нормально

Комментарий Alex Titov